# getting fullnumber with countrycode from jQuery International Telephone Input Plugin

Tags: jquery

i am using jQuery Interrnational Telephone Input Plugin for getting countrycode along with the phone number.
html code

```
<div class="form-group">
<input type="tel"  placeholder="Phone*" id="telephone" name="telephone" class="form-control">
</div>
```

initialistion of plugin

```
jQuery("#telephone").intlTelInput({
   // options here
   allowDropdown:true,
   autoHideDialCode:true,
   autoPlaceholder:"polite",
   separateDialCode:true,
    customPlaceholder:null

  });
```

how to grt the full country code with the phone number.

Answer (score 0):

I was not able to recreate the plugin using jQuery. But see an example below with vanilla JS. The plugin has a public method `getNumber()` through which you can get the number.

```js
var input = document.querySelector("#telephone");
let iti = window.intlTelInput(input, {
  // options here
  allowDropdown: true,
  autoHideDialCode: true,
  autoPlaceholder: "polite",
  separateDialCode: true,
  customPlaceholder: null,
  utilsScript: "https://raw.githack.com/jackocnr/intl-tel-input/master/build/js/utils.js"

});

$(".get-number").on("click", function() {
  console.log(iti.getNumber());
});
```

```css
.get-number {
  padding: 0.5em 1em;
  background-color: lightblue;
  border-radius: 0.2em;
  display: inline-block;
  margin: 1em 0;
  cursor: pointer;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://raw.githack.com/jackocnr/intl-tel-input/41735773e78c39aad6aaee53a6126215f64aeb57/build/js/intlTelInput.js"></script>
<link href="https://raw.githack.com/jackocnr/intl-tel-input/master/build/css/intlTelInput.min.css" rel="stylesheet" />
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="form-group">
  <input type="tel" placeholder="Phone*" id="telephone" name="telephone" class="form-control">
</div>

<div class='get-number'>
  Get Number
</div>
```